# Django - creating a main page without an extension with request processing (not direct to template)

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I'm very new to Django, while going through the tutorials how to start different apps inside of a project is clear to me, but not setting up the index page of the entire website.

Inside of my project folder it looks something like:

Projectname

App1

App2

App3

What I want to do is create a url with path looking something like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('index.urls')), #Homepage url
    path('App1/', include('App1.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('App2/', include('App2.urls')),
    path('App3/', include('App3.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So that you can visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (or website.com) and see an index page with a corresponding view that I can use to show content from a database.

Maybe its as simple as creating an index-app and setting the path to (''), but I haven't been able to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create `index` view inside app (e.g. app1), and use this view direcly with `urlpatterns`, like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from app1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index), #Homepage url
    path('App1/', include('App1.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('App2/', include('App2.urls')),
    path('App3/', include('App3.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Or if you'd like to keep `index` in `undex.urls`, you should add to `index.urls` file empty path:

```
# index urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]


# project urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('index.urls')), #Homepage url
    path('App1/', include('App1.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('App2/', include('App2.urls')),
    path('App3/', include('App3.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```